# Angular upgrade 8 to 9, incompatible peer dependency

Tags: angular

I'm getting the following errors when attempting to upgrade Angular 8 to 9.

```
Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
```

I'm currently at ng-bootstrap version 5.0. What is this telling me I need to do?

Comment: Look for a version of `ng-bootstrap` compatible with `@angular/core` 9 instead of 7

Comment: [Release 6 starts targetting angular 9](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/commit/a46597d1b45ad716c0aa55b4a83729f509f95462#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519R66)

Comment: This is why, when building angular libraries, you give your library the same major version as the angular version you're targetting. ngb didn't

Comment: So I would need to install nbg 6 before updating angular to 9, correct?

Comment: I cannot update ngb to 6.0 without already having angular 9.0

Comment: Thinking the same.  Does `ng update` not work and update the ngb package for you?

Comment: @Pieterjan any other advice here? Seems like a catch-22. I can't update either without the other being updated first

Comment: You can always edit your package.json manually, change everything related to angular to `~9.0.0` and ng-bootstrap to `~6.0.0`, run `npm update` and resolve the conflicts manually.  But I'm affraid this will skip some default angular migrations...

Comment: Apparently [here's](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=7.0-9.0) a guide where you can select your from and to version to get the instructions. But ofc it doesn't include other libraries...